# Set Maximum Value of Progress bar from Big Integer

Tags: android, kotlin, numberformatexception

I am new to Kotlin and learning it to my own. I have a String as:

```
 "202026141059"
```

I am converting it into an Int Value and setting it to the progress bar maximum value as:

```
 availableCreditProgress.max = queryBalancePicResponseData.available_credit!!.toString().toInt()
```

The problem is its giving me the **java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "202026141059"**

Can somebody please identify what I'm doing wrong with it?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: progress bar maximum value 100. then you can not set 202026141059. it's long value not integer. convert into long.

Answer (score 1):

`Int` goes only from `Int.MIN_VALUE`, i.e. `-2147483648`, to `Int.MAX_VALUE`, i.e. `2147483647`. Your value exceeds that... Try `toLong` instead if you require the value somewhere.

As ProgressBar only allows `Int` itself, try to scale it down there... I would go for max `100`.

So if you have your max value of `202026141059` that is actually your `100` in the progressbar... so you start with `0`, if you reach `2020261410` you switch to `1` (or you round it), etc.

Here is a basic example... of course you may deliver your values in another way and use it also differently ;-) I just printed it for now:

```
val maxValue = "202026141059".toLong()
var currentProgress = -1L
val scale = 100000
(0..(maxValue/scale)).forEach { curr ->
    currentProgress = (curr * 100 * scale / maxValue ).also {
        if (it != currentProgress) {
            println(it)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: progressbar only accepts an INTEGER for maximum value

Comment: how can i use ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to deal with such big numbers that are not suitable for the ProgressBar, then you have to scale them, with a factor say `1000`.   
So the value `202026141059 must be divided by 1000 = 202026141.059` and by rounding this number you will get `202026141` and this will be the `max` 
This must be done with all the values that you assign to the ProgressBar.